# How to Assign string in version attrbute of WIX project

Tags: wix

I am having installer with version 1.2.3.4, which is hardcoded in wxs file as below:

```
<Product Id="B91BEF19-0975-DB9185E716FC" Name="Installer" Language="1033" Version="1.2.3.4" Manufacturer="XX" UpgradeCode="c2a8ba27-bb8-186cbcd4d743">
```

Now i need to change the version like "1.2.3.4_temp".i.e, assigning the string to version.
As we know version attribute takes x.x.x.x and x as integer.
Is any way to get the version as 1.2.3.4_temp?

Is any way to assign ProductName (as xxxx) to version in wxs file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use product version as a **numeric value**.

Though [Wix toolset documentation](https://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/xsd/wix/product.html) says **Version** attribute as *The product's version string*, you need to look up at the [Windows Installer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/property-reference) documentation for details about **Version** attribute.

It says for **ProductVersion** : "String format of the product version as a numeric value. (Required)"

For details about **ProductVersion**, please go to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/productversion) link.